# How to find the difference in a Map between two Strings based on their integer values?

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, difference

My question is how do I loop through this Map and find the difference between some two Strings based on their integer values. I know I need an "i" somewhere in my for-loop but I don't know how to implement it.

```
float getDifference(Map<String, Integer> qualities)
 {
    String myQuality = "";
    String yourQuality = "";
    float answer = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<qualities.size(); i++)
       {
         answer = qualities.get(myQuality) - qualities.get(yourQuality);
         }
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: why is a for loop needed, even if you do this answer = qualities.get(myQuality) - qualities.get(yourQuality); you will get the answer.

Comment: I'm looping through a map of qualities that have some integer value. My qualities will not be changing but "you" have multiple qualities that I need to loop through and find the distance between each of "your" qualities and mine. Thats why I have the Map. Should I not initialize String myQuality and yourQuality?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the loop if you know the value of `myQuality` and `yourQuality`.

Answer (score 0):

just do this no need of loop:

`qualities.get(myQuality) - qualities.get(yourQuality)`

Answer (score 0):

Still not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but here's how to loop over a hash map:

```
float getDifference(Map<String, Integer> qualities)
{
    String myQuality = "";
    float answer = 0;
    for(Entry<String, Integer> quality : qualities.entrySet())
    {
         answer += qualities.get(myQuality) - quality.getValue();
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Give us a little more info (concrete example) and we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the difference between the mapped values of the two strings,you can do the following.

```
float getDifference(Map<String, Integer> qualities, String str1, String str2)
{
  Integer int1 = qualities.get(str1);
  Integer int2 = qualities.get(str2);
  if(int1 != null && int2 != null)
    return int1.intValue() - int2.intValue();

  return -9999;
}
```

**Explanation**

HashMap stores Key Value Pair. Key will be unique here through out the map. We can use map.get(key) to get the value corresponding to that key.

HashMap can store only objects, so we can store object of class Integer. While using put(), int to Integer conversion happens automatically by compiler. But while getting the value back we should check for null.

Keep -9999 or some value which can tell you that either your first string or second string are not present in the map as key